# Firebase multi-path updates just overwrites the supposed node

Tags: javascript, firebase

In the code below I am trying to use a cloud function to do a multiple update of setting some of my fields to a new value, but it just results to overwriting each of the nodes. I don't really understand this behavior, cos I just needed a simple update.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.onJobBid_Status = functions.database
    .ref("/JobBids/{jobId}/{bidId}/status")
    .onWrite((event) => {

        let newStatus = event.data.val();

        let updates = {};
        updates["/Jobs/" + event.params.jobId] = { status: newStatus,  };
        updates["/Users/" + event.params.bidId + "/JobBids/" + event.params.jobId] = { status: newStatus, level:"4", color:"green" };


        return admin.database().ref().update(updates);

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call update, the Firebase server:

- Loops through the properties/paths of the `updates`.
- For each property/path, performs a `set()` operation.

So while you can update specific paths, at each path the operation is a regular `set()`. This means it replaces the data under each path.

The solution is to have the entire path to the lowest-level property in your key. So in your case:

```
let updates = {};
updates["/Jobs/" + event.params.jobId+"/status"] = newStatus;
let jobPath = "/Users/" + event.params.bidId + "/JobBids/" + event.params.jobId;
updates[jobPath+/status"] = newStatus;
updates[jobPath+/level"] = "4"; // consider storing this as a number
updates[jobPath+/color"] = "green" ;
```

With these `updates`, you will only replace the values of the `status`, `level` and `color` properties.